# Is it possible to force the Spacings in Grid to actually be 0?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to use `Grid[]` with `Spacings->{0,0}` but the distance between the items doens't actually get $0$. It becomes something like:

[image]

Is it possible to actually for the distance to be 0?

Add: Something that could also help me, given a string, say `"a"` can we make Mathematica treat it as image?

Comment: `Rasterize[expr]` returns the image of the rasterization of the displayed form of `expr`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
Grid[Partition[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
     ImageSize -> 20] & /@ Map[ColorData[64],
    Range[100]], UpTo[16], 16], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

or

```
Grid[Partition[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}],
      White, Inset["a", Center]},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
     ImageSize -> 20] & /@ Map[ColorData[64],
    Range[100]], UpTo[16], 16], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This will help me tremendously. Thanks.